# How to boot to root shell when GRUB recovery menu fails to load a shell?

Tags: root, recovery-mode

Can't seem to [boot into root shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell) in recovery mode from GRUB. I try booting into recovery mode from the GRUB menu and don't ever get a shell, just log messages from the kernel bootup. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> don't really give me anything important either.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

u can manually edit ur grub file.
For example, when booting up, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> to get into grub2, and press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit
the commandline, change the commandline: 
append init=/bin/sh

`linux  init=/bin/sh`

and if you are lucky, you can get in a shell.
[How to boot GRUB2 into the simplest Linux shell ?](https://superuser.com/questions/215590/how-to-boot-grub2-into-the-simplest-linux-shell/215604#215604)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm new-ish to kernel boot parameters, so yeah. Main thing was that I needed to uninstall Gnome-Do as it would lock up the computer and would start on boot. I don't have the computer in my possession anymore (it was a friends), so I unfortunately can't test your solution, but I'll take you at your word.

Answer (score 2):

Selecting 'recovery mode' should normally give you a menu from which you can choose to get a root shell or various other options.  If you don't get that menu, something is broken.  What are the last few messages you see?

Comment: If you're selecting "recovery mode" that _in itself_ means something is broken...