# How do I boot into a root shell?

Tags: boot, grub2, root, recovery-mode

When booting to the graphical desktop fails we sometimes are recommended to boot into a "root shell" or to boot in "recovery mode".

How do I do that?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

### for 12.04.3 LTS and later

During boot, press **and hold** <kbd>Shift</kbd> *(for BIOS)* or <kbd>ESC</kbd> *(for UEFI)*. This will bring up the Grub2 menu from where we can select "Advanced options for Ubuntu".

[image]

After that we will be able to select the kernel we wish to boot in *"Recovery mode"*:

[image]

This will lead us to the advanced options. By selecting *"Enable networking"* we gain access to our network and the internet for upgrades or downloads, and we will also **mount our hard drives in read/write mode** in case we need to edit files.

[image]

After the network has loaded, and fielsystems were mounted we will be presented again with the menu, from where we can choose *"Drop to a root shell prompt"*:

[image]

Note that we are root in this shell. Hence no sudo is needed for administrative tasks. This also means we have full access to all files, and we may cause irreversible damage to our system if we made a mistake.

If we had not enabled read/write access with *"Enable networking"* the filesystem will be mounted **read only**, and we are unable to edit files.

In case we don't have access to a network, or this was not desired, we can remount our filesystem(s) giving write access with the following command:

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

From the root shell type `exit` to go back to the menu.

### for 12.04.0 LTS or earlier

During boot, press **and hold** <kbd>Shift</kbd> *(for BIOS)* or <kbd>ESC</kbd> *(for UEFI)*.  This will bring up the Grub2 boot menu from where we can select "recovery mode" (usually the second boot entry).

[image]

This will lead to the Grub2 recovery menu:

[image]

*"Drop to root shell prompt"* gives you a command line root environment from where you can access your files as root (no `sudo` required). After having done your work on your files you can leave the command line shell by

```
exit
```

Choose *"Resume normal boot"* to proceed booting as usual.

---

**Note:** see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/15284/3940) for a solution when the Grub recovery menu does not load the shell.

---

Comment: I just installed 12.04 LTS, and it looks like I have the recovery menu listed under ">= 12.10". So I just followed those instructions  instead and everything worked fine.

Comment: @tir38: oh good point, thank you. It has changed with the updated LTS release then.

Comment: after enable networking, it doesn't goes back to menu again. Need help

Comment: @SanjeevKumarDangi: try with `exit`.

Comment: my computer just goes zombie while enabling networking. i have a fresh install of 12.04.3 LTS server. i'm trying to get to the root shell to delete my encrypted home folder as its causing 100% cpu usage with lxde. i had to ctrl+alt+c to resume booting, trying again now. its odd, a similar thing happened during partitioning while i was installing. maybe its my harddrive, i'm unsure. i wonder if perhaps its attempting to mount the filesystem of my Windows 7 install, hence the freezing?

Comment: My systems (14.04) hangs when trying to enable network and mounting the filesystem. When I press CTRL+C the systems goes to normal boot. When I go to root access, I can enable read/write with the following command: `mount -o rw,remount /`, and then I can use the terminal to change whatever I need to change.

Comment: @SPRBRN: thank you for this important notice. I edited that into the answer.