# How do I deal with 'sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner'?

Tags: 12.10, sudo

Whenever I try to install or remove something using terminal it gives the following error message:

```
bluebird@bluebird:~$ sudo apt-get update
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
bluebird@bluebird:~$ sudo apt-get remove vlc
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
bluebird@bluebird:~$ sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

Comment: are you trying to install from non-admin account?

Comment: yes.....but using sudo commands we can also perform the required task as an administrator. i always install/remove programs this way. today i installed vlc player through ubuntu software centre. after that i noticed such error. i remove vlc using soft centr. but no help.

Comment: Hi Loy, welcome to Askubuntu. I want to encourage you to use some formatting in your question. That makes it easier to read it. One practical question: can you run `ls -al /usr/lib/sudo/` and tell us what the permissions are for sudoers.so?

Comment: use `su -` then press enter and enter password

Comment: Wonder why Linux LET'S you run `sudo chmod g+w -R /usr/lib/` if it breaks stuff.

Answer (score 9):

22h has it right, but because of the sudoers.so issue, you won't be able to run sudo to fix the permissions.

So you are going to have to drop to a root shell as described here: [How do I boot into a root shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell)

(Essentially rebooting, holding the left Shift key for Grub to come up, "Advanced Options" "recovery mode" "network" and "root").

Then you will need to:

```
chown root:root /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
chmod 644 /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
```

Which should solve this issue.

Comment: Alternately, if `su` is installed, you can use it to switch users to root, assuming you know the root password.  I *think* it's one of the default packages, but I can't say for sure. (I only use Ubuntu server so not sure if the client install prompts you to set the root password)

Comment: `root` passwords are considered harmful.

Answer (score 6):

Try this,

```
ls -l /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
```

If the first word of the output is something other than

```
-rwxr-xr-x
```

we have to remove the write permissions from group and others.

```
pkexec chmod go-w /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
```

Comment: I have only ssh access to the server. And this answer saved me.

Comment: This also works on Ubuntu 14.04. But I don't understand how this happened in the first place. I don't think I set it by myself.