# Why does compiz crash? (Ubuntu 12.10 under virtualbox)

Tags: compiz, virtualbox

I am using a Fujitsu LH531 Laptop with windows 7. I tried installing ubuntu 12.10 using virtual box. After installation, when i reboot for the first time, it shows the login screen. But after logging in, there is nothing, then an error message saying compiz has closed unexpectedly and therefor the desktop is unusable.

I have reinstalled many times, but every single time it happens..

I have searched the forums, topics, discussions, questions.. and i suspect it has something to do with my NVIDIA card.

Details:

> Ubuntu 12.10
>   Virtualbox 4.2.6
>   Windows 7

Can anyone help? I don't need nvidia graphics, I just want to use ubuntu normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to run Unity in Ubuntu 12.10 we need to enable 3D acceleration in Virtual Box. This is done by both, providing 3D acceleration in the VM settings, and by installing the virtual graphics driver provided with the Guest Additions.

The normal procedure to install the guest additions will not work as we won't have a graphical desktop. We therefore will have to boot Ubuntu into a terminal shell.

Please see the following questions on a how to do this:

- [How do I install Guest Additions in a VirtualBox VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox)
- [How do I boot into a root shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell)

Comment: Note also that the real video card that you are using, a long as it is working in the host system doesn't affect at all Virtual Box.

Comment: Hi, I managed to install Guests Additions, and now I am able to have some access to the system. However, the launcher is missing! I can only use the terminal by ctrl-alt-t

Comment: Try to `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` from the terminal for all fixes. You may have to install the guest additions again after that. 12.10 plays not so nice with Virtual Box, unfortunately.