# Login loop with fresh install

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, login

I am trying to install 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04.3 as a Guest Host on VirtualBox V5.0.6, on Windows 7.  Mind you, this is a fresh install.  The very first (and all subsequent times!) that I try to log in I get into the infinite login loop referred to elsewhere ([Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop), [Ubuntu 14.04.3 going into login loop on Virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/677997/ubuntu-14-04-3-going-into-login-loop-on-virtualbox), and [Stuck in a user log-in loop on startup (fresh install)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/542067/stuck-in-a-user-log-in-loop-on-startup-fresh-install), as well as others) and no joy!

Ubunutu gets as far as displaying the main desktop menu at the top, then a black screen for a few seconds, then back to the login window. Logging in to a terminal, I see the following in .xsession-errors:

```
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd respawning too fast, stopped
init: gnome-session (Unity) main process (2329) terminated with status 1
init: logrotate main process (2226) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-bluetooth main process (2396) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-power main process (2398) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-datetime main process (2400) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-printers main process (2409) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-session main process (2414) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-application main process (2426) killed by TERM signal
init: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
```

Excuse me for emphasizing, but this is a new computer, with latest, just installed, VirtualBox, attempting to install the latest stable Ubuntu LTS, and I cannot log in.  Every option was defaults.  Nothing tricky.  It just doesn't work, and it never has worked!  What gives?

I have tried everything that makes sense by logging in  via a terminal, but I can't login to the desktop no matter what I try.

The computer is a Lenova T450S, with Intel HD Graphics 5500 display adapter.

Any ideas???  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because I need Ubuntu wicked bad, I tried the same thing with 12.04 LTS, and it works fine.  I would still like to use 14.04, so I'm still interested, but in the meantime things are working.  For grins, I'm going to clone my working VM and try upgrading to 14.04 LTS and see if that works; I'll post my results for anyone who might be interested!

Comment: Okay, so here is a clue - when trying to upgrade, I get the following warning; I'm still going to try, as I made a clone!  

`Your graphics hardware may not be fully supported in Ubuntu 14.04.

Running the 'unity' desktop environment is not fully supported by your graphics hardware. You will maybe end up in a very slow environment after the upgrade. Our advice is to keep the LTS version for now. For more information see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Bugs/UpdateManagerWarningForUnity3D Do you still want to continue with the upgrade?`

Comment: Yup, the upgrade fails !  Infinite login loop !

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: First check your computer's BIOS settings and ensure that Intel virtualization settings are turned on! The below is a workaround that worked even though my BIOS settings for Intel virtualization were turned off. I was able to only install 32-bit virtual machines on my 64-bit laptop, so that is why I ran into this issue. Below is the workaround that worked for me, but after turning BIOS settings for Intel virtualization I no longer needed the workaround on 32-bit installs, and I was also able to use 64-bit VMs.

---

I was banging my head against the same issue. It turns out the error boiled down to

> "compiz crashed with SIGILL"

After some online research, I found that I needed to install the VirtualBox Guest Additions from the terminal and enable 3D Acceleration in the VM's display settings. This worked for the latest version of VirtualBox as of 11/28/2015 and the latest 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS iso.

The article here : 
[Why does compiz crash under virtual box?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256080/why-does-compiz-crash-ubuntu-12-10-under-virtualbox)

led me to the solution : [How do I install guest additions in a virtualbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm)

The relevant steps are to

1. Enable 3D Acceleration from the VirtualBox Manager Settings menu.

   - Settings > Display > Screen > Enable 3D Acceleration
2. Boot your VM to the login screen.
3. Switch to a TTY using `ctrl` + `alt` + `F1`
4. Login as your user.
5. Insert Guest Additions

   - Devices > Insert Guest Additions CD image...
6. Finally run the installer script, VBoxLinuxAdditions.run, as root:

.

```
mount /dev/cdrom /mnt
cd /mnt
sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
reboot
```