# Ubuntu 12.04: Problem editing file in recovery mode using the shell

Tags: boot, permissions, fstab, recovery-mode

I'm pretty new to ubuntu/linux and I guess I messed up my `/etc/fstab` file. Ubuntu (12.04) won't boot anymore. I've found some tips on the internet on how to fix this, but I didn't manage to get them working.

What I've tried so far is to reboot and enter recovery mode shell  and edit the `/etc/fstab` file using `#nano /etc/fstab`.

I figured this won't work since the the mounted filesystem is read only. Then I tried `#mount -n -o remount,rw /` at the shell in order to remount the filesystem as writable. But if I enter now `#nano /etc/fstab` I get the line `bash: /usr/bin/nano: Permission denied.` Am I missing something here?

Another option I've tried is to create a bootable USB drive (I don't have a CD drive). This didn't work. I created a bootable USB stick and it boots on other machines, but not on my laptop (yes, I doublechecked the BIOS for the boot-order).
Any help would be very very much appreciated.

Comment: Well that seems weird, so you cannot even run the nano program? What is output when you enter the command `ls -l /usr/bin/nano`?

Comment: You did [this process](http://askubuntu.com/a/92558/62483) to enter in recovery mode?

Comment: @Wolter, when I enter this **before** attempting to remount, I get the following: **lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 May 9 2012 /usr/bin/nano -> /bin/nano**. If I then try to remount using **#mount -n -o remount,rw /** then I get "Permission denied" on **every** command that I enter.

Comment: @Lucio, no, I didn't follow these exact steps. In my case, the Grub menu comes up automatically (I don't have to press Shift). But apart from this it is identical: I select **Recovery mode** on the first screen and **root** on the next one.

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved. I checked the partition table using fdisk. I figured that there are more then 1 partition (one for example DELLUTILITY). I assumed that simply remounting using the line `#mount -n -o remount,rw /` might mount the wrong partition. So I tried `#mount -n -o remount,rw /dev/sda3 /` instead and that worked just fine. I was able to get r/w access to the fstab file, fix it using nano, reboot and be happy.

Thanks anyways for your interest.