# No icons on main screen on VirtualBox

Tags: 12.10, virtualbox, icons, guest-additions

I've tried everything, I've uninstalled and reinstalled, I've tried adding guest additions, nothing is working.

EDIT: I should also add I've been using this guide to getting VB set up: http://alexmk.hubpages.com/hub/How-To-Install-Ubuntu-Steam-TF2-under-VirtualBox-on-Windows-to-get-Linux-Tux-Promo

Comment: Please also update your 12.10 guest OS (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` before installing the guest additions.

Comment: Let me state that I"m a noob at anything when it comes to Linux. I'm unable to open the terminal with Ctrl + Alt + T, maybe its another error entirely?

Comment: In Virtualbox you can open a terminal shell TTY1 with `HOST`+`F1`. Alternatively [boot a root shell](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell) for upgrading.

Comment: I performed a root shell booting, attempted to add the guest additions, still didn't work, its giving me an error, VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED

Answer (score 0):

it seems a problem related to Nautilus, Restart nautilus to fix it. easiest way to do this is to open file explorer

Answer (score 0):

I have two systems, both running Windows 7 64-bit as the host operating system.  I did an install of VirtualBox (4.2.10) and Ubuntu 12.10 on both.  It worked fine on my Dell desktop, but I got the icon-less screen on my Lenovo laptop.  There were other problems on the laptop, such as Compiz crashing, and taking *minutes* to open a terminal session.  After several re-installs and trying various things, I tried installing Ubuntu 12.04 instead.  Worked first time with no special tweaks.

Based on this post (https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=51727&start=45) you *might* have better luck with a different display adapter.