# Cannot install guest additions in Ubuntu 13.04 on VBox 4.2.12

Tags: virtualbox

I've had the same issue with the previous version but I was able to fix it. I've just updated to ubuntu 13.04 and now have the same problem again. Basically, I cannot install the guest additions from the desktop because the compiz application fails and I just see the background, there is no way for me to autorun the vbox additions. So I need to open the command shell from GRUB, mount the cd and run the Linux Additions from there. Everything is fine for step one and two. However, when I try

```
sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

I receive an error message regarding Read-only file system.

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `/tmp/selfgz741': Read-only file system
Cannot create target directory /tmp/selfgz741
```

Here is the permissions for the /tmp folder:

```
drwxrwxrwt  root  root  tmp
```

I'm wondering what is required so that I can write in the /tmp folder. 
Also, when I'm in the console, i'm connected as root@virtualbox.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Open up a terminal and cd to the directory where VBoxLinuxAdditions.run is located

example: `cd /media/user1/VBOXADDITIONS_4.2.12_84980/`

And run the command below

```
sudo sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Comment: Worked foe me in lubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 1):

Don't open the shell from GRUB. Boot Ubuntu normally. Then, press Ctrl+Alt+F1 and login to the 1st virtual terminal. Next, install the guest additions. Finally, reboot with "sudo reboot".

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the permissions of the /tmp directory. Open your terminal and type:

```
sudo chown <your_username>:<your_group> /tmp
```

Then try again. Hope that helps.

Comment: Is there some way to see which group I belong to? Is there a default group my user should be part of?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350141/in-unix-linux-how-to-you-find-out-what-group-a-given-user-is-in-via-command-line

Comment: I can see the groups my user belongs to but is there one group I should choose in particular? I've tried with group adm but I still have the directory problem when I run the command.

Comment: choose the sudo group .

Comment: I've tried the following command `sudo chown user:sudo /tmp` and i received a message regarding the ownership change. However, the issue is still there when I run the guest additions command. Also when I do `ls -l` I still see root next to tmp (this might be expected)

Answer (score 0):

The [root shell we access from Grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell) will mount all filesystems as read only. To enable read/write access (including to the /tmp directory) while installing Guest Additions we need to enable networking before we drop to the root shell prompt:

[image]