# Error upon booting Ubuntu in Virtualbox - SMBus error

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, virtualbox

I used to have a different PC, with Ubuntu on it. That PC broke, so I wanted Ubuntu back, but not fully on my laptop.
So, I installed Virtualbox, followed all steps. But at boot, I get

1. The regular VB boot-up.
2. The purple Ubuntu screen w/ a man at the
       bottom next to a keyboard
3. A black screen w/ a blinking cursor
4. Another purple screen with text saying: Ubuntu 14.04, and small dots
       under it
5. After about a minute, some text will show saying:

[image: Ubuntu Error: SMBus error]

I can't figure out what to do. I've been to many links, also this (which was most suggested):
[SMBus/ BIOS error while booting Ubuntu in VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298290/smbus-bios-error-while-booting-ubuntu-13-04-in-virtualbox)
But the steps aren't clear. I can't get TO the OS, I can only see this at boot-up.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: I found that if I leave it, it eventually gets into the OS. Any steps from there?

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298290/smbus-bios-error-while-booting-ubuntu-in-virtualbox)

Same problem at my installation, VirtualBox 4.3.18 and Ubuntu 14.04, and I managed to solve it following instructions at given link.