# How do I upgrade the BIOS or use "force_addr= 0xaddr"?

Tags: gnome, virtualbox

I am absolutely new in Linux system. I have installed Gnome Ubuntu-16.04 in a virtual machine using vbox in Windows 8.1. After installing, it says to restart. When I clicked to restart, I receive the following message:

[image]

How can I recover from this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have fully booted into your VM open a terminal and type `sudo su` to become root (you will be prompted for your password) then type the following:

```
# to check the module is loaded
lsmod | grep intel_rapl
```

If it is loaded blacklist it in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` by adding it to the end of the file: the next line will do that

```
echo "blacklist intel_rapl" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

After that only thing left to do is update the initramfs by:

```
update-initramfs -u -k all
```

After that you can become a normal user again by typing `exit` then close the terminal and reboot the VM.

The solution I needed myself a couple of times already and I found it [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/316927/522934) and adopted it to your problem.