# Ubuntu Install Error 16.04- Upgrade BIOS

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, bios

I'm currently trying to install ubuntu 16.04 through a virtual machine (using VirtualBox) however, I am getting this error:

[image: Error Image]

I'm not particularly good with with computers so I don't really know what I'm doing wrong. I have followed the installation steps correctly to my knowledge.

I am using MacOS.

Comment: Please next time copy/paste the error and don't insert an image.

Comment: The message you used in the title is trivial and can be ignored. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/298290/smbus-bios-error-while-booting-ubuntu-in-virtualbox Fix: install guest additions according to the link.