# VirtualBox XUbuntu 16.04 - Bootloader won't start

Tags: boot, grub2, virtualbox, xubuntu

I am using VirtualBox with XUbuntu 16.04. All was going fine before I install guest additions, but after the install, the OS doesn't start. I think it is the boatloader that fails (btw I am noob at Ubuntu, and I read that's called by GRUB2). The only way that I can start Ubuntu is going to the 'Recovery Mode' and then start it there. That is what happens when I turn on my VB:

[image: Ubuntu won't start.]

After searching for a bit, I discover an application that gives you the boot-info, unfortunately I don't know how to read it... The link is:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/25682089/

Thank you!

Comment: The paste-bin link leads to nowhere.

Comment: Possible related: [SMBus/ BIOS error while booting Ubuntu in VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/a/726285) and [What does `nomodeset` do](https://askubuntu.com/a/207177).

Answer (score 1):

Been looking for a solution to this for a while now, finally found it here:

https://askubuntu.com/a/726285

Basically:

- Append `nomodeset` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` (after `quiet splash`)
- Run `sudo update-grub`
- Should reboot normally now.

See here for an explanation of what nomodeset does (shouldn't have an impact once booted):

https://askubuntu.com/a/207177