# Ubuntu 22.04 not starting after upgrading from 21.10 on HyperV

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, hyper-v, smbus

I've upgraded my Kubuntu 21.10 VM today, to 22.04 LTS. The install went fine, and everythin was upgraded. After it reboot, however, I'm simply met with the following message:

```
SMBus base address uninitialized - upgrade BIOS or use force_addr=0xaddr
```

The KDE environment never boots, even if I leave it awhile.

I can switch to a different terminal, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, for example, and log into the terminal, but I cannot get the GUI to load.

I've seen this question, [SMBus/ BIOS error while booting Ubuntu in VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298290/smbus-bios-error-while-booting-ubuntu-in-virtualbox), which has the same error but in VirtualBox, and tried blacklisting both `i2c_piix4` and `intel_rapl`; same result. Checking `lsmod` afterwards, it was still loaded even though blacklisted. I also tried putting the black list in the file `/etc/modprobe.d/no_i2c_piix4.conf`; same result and still loaded.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening, and how to fix?

Comment: Have you made any progress on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the problem here was that the VM was a Gen 1 VM, and 22.04 needs a Gen 2 VM (or at least, I could not get it to work as a Gen 1 VM).

Upgrading an existing VM from a Gen 1 to a Gen 2 isn't possible. What you can do, however, is delete the existing VM (make sure you don't delete it's vhd files), and then create a new Gen 2 VM and attack the old vhd files to it. This *should* "upgrade" the system to a Gen 2; though apparently it is a 1 way process.

I also noted, through research, that you should disable Secure Boot on the VM; I had this off any way, but if you *do* have it enabled and are having difficulty, then I would suggest trying to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Got similar error.  The error message I got is `Unable to find a valid framebuffer device`, which is prompted in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Copy from the [link](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/generic-solution-when-install-gets-framebuffer-mode-fails.111577/) in proxmox forum, it seems that the display device could not be found.  To fix:-

1. Ctrl + Alt + F2 to enter console
2. `lspci` to find pci id of the VGA device, e.g. 00:08.0
3. `cd /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`
4. `sudo nano <your config name>.conf`, e.g. hyperv.conf
5. Put below content in the file.  Your PCI ID may be different

   ```
    Section "Device"
        Identifier "Card0"
        Driver "fbdev"
        BusID "pci0:08:0:0:"
    EndSection
   ```
6. Save and close
7. `startx`
8. If success, you should immediately see the GUI loaded.

For information.  I got this problem when converting a lubuntu from KVM and VM-Workstation to Hyper-V platform.

Ref:
https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/generic-solution-when-install-gets-framebuffer-mode-fails.111577/