# How to change my password?

Tags: 13.04, password-recovery

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 through wubi file, where we set username & passwd preinstalling of Ubuntu,but now I couldn't login with my username even though I typed the correct password, as it is showing it as wrong password.

Comment: @guntbert - The solution (boot to recovery mode) applies to wubi

Comment: I tried both left and right shift but i couldnt boot into recovery mode

Answer (score 5):

Boot into a root shell:
[How do I boot into a root shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell)

Then change the password for you user

```
sudo passwd <username>
```