# Ati driver with HD7470M laptop screen backlight not working

Tags: 14.04, laptop, fglrx

I need to install the ATI proprietary driver on my laptop (Asus K54HR) as I use it for gaming.
My problem is, it doesn't matter what I try, I have always the same result black screen and I have to reinstall ubuntu.
It works fine with external monitors but not with the laptop screen.
I use Ubuntu 14.04 in dual boot with windows 7 both 64bit.
I tested it with 12.04 64 bit too.
My graphic card is Radeon HD 7470M Seymour series.
What can I do?

Thank you.

Comment: What method did you try to install the driver? When are you getting the black screen?

Comment: I've tried:
GUI installation
Manual Installation
creating Ubuntu package

and I always have the black screen as soon as I reboot the system

Comment: Do use use Ubuntu for gaming? Or jus windows? If just windows then you only need to install the driver on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you're using the [latest driver version from AMD](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86#amd-catalyst-packages). If those aren't working, I would recommend trying the "Latest Beta" drivers. At this point in time, the release notes for the Beta version mention "Ubuntu 14.04 Support", so it might be a good idea especially to try those. (I don't know if it was already there, or what "Ubuntu 14.04 support" means exactly, or what.)

Anyway, when you extract the .zip file and install the Beta driver (try the normal install and the package generation), it still might not be working. If it isn't, reboot into a Recovery Mode root shell prompt ([howto](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell)) and run:

```
aticonfig --initial
```

and then reboot with `reboot` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>.

However, I would be very surprised if the package generation method doesn't make an xorg.conf for you.

Comment: If my solution doesn't work, put the output of `dmesg | grep fglrx` into your question.

Comment: black screen, it does not start even with fail safe graphic so I cannot try dmesg | grep fglrx

Comment: Even a recovery mode root shell prompt?

Comment: I've tried connecting an external monitor, and everything works fine! so the problem must be my laptop screen. as per the dmesg here the result:

Comment: [   13.851841] fglrx: module license 'Proprietary. (C) 2002 - ATI Technologies, Starnberg, GERMANY' taints kernel.
[   13.866332] fglrx: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[   13.876406] <6>[fglrx] Maximum main memory to use for locked dma buffers: 3766 MBytes.
[   13.876704] <6>[fglrx]   vendor: 1002 device: 6760 count: 1
[   13.877101] <6>[fglrx] ioport: bar 4, base 0xd000, size: 0x100
[   13.877304] <6>[fglrx] Kernel PAT support is enabled
[   13.877332] <6>[fglrx] module loaded - fglrx 14.20.7 [May 22 2014] with 1 minors

Comment: [   19.082286] fglrx_pci 0000:01:00.0: irq 55 for MSI/MSI-X
[   19.082886] <6>[fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1143
[   19.082972] <6>[fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1144
[   19.083057] <6>[fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1145
[   19.083149] <6>[fglrx] IRQ 55 Enabled
[   19.126289] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Shared offset:0, size:1000000 
[   19.126291] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:f866000, size:4000 
[   19.126293] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:f86a000, size:496000 
[   19.126294] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:3fff4000, size:c000

Comment: my laptop screen seems to have the back illumination turned off with the fglrx driver. if I put the screen direct under light I can see it's working but without back illumination

Comment: ok you should add all these details to your question...