# Not able to login into ubuntu 12.04

Tags: login, login-screen

I am now using ubuntu 12.04. I have problem with login. It wait me for log time even though I have enter right password.And nothing happen after waiting. I try to login from guest account but same problem occur with guest account.

Comment: can you log in via recovery mode?

Comment: how to login from recovery mode? If u have any document or video can you please share with me

Comment: Look at this answer, if you can log in here then it's nothing wrong with the account. http://askubuntu.com/a/92558/10698

Comment: Able to login from recovery mode but from graphical user interface nothing happen after entering password only desktop showing login screen again

Answer (score 0):

enter via recovery mode and make sure your computer is up to date, do the following commands to upgrade the software. This could resolve the issue because this sounds like a bug to me.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

`dist-upgrade` install new kernels it **doesn't** upgrade the system to a new release of Ubuntu.

If this doesn't work, then I would upgrade to 14.04, because I think this is a bug and newer software most likely wont have this issue.

I would start by downloading Ubuntu 14.04 and put it on a USB(live-usb) and boot from it. You can upgrade your current installation from there and you don't have to make a fresh install. This involves less risk than by upgrading via `do-release-upgrade` form the terminal because you already have all the necessary files on your USB.

But I would also make a backup of all your files first, or those you can't lose.

Here are some alternatives on how to backup your files, there are others but these are the ones I would try.

- **live-usb**
  Boot the USB -> try Ubuntu -> mount the partition -> backup the files.
- **graphical via the network**
  via the network when the computer is running, network -> your computer -> log in with user/password if
  you have installed and configured this (your home folder needs to be
  shared with the network for this to work).
- **SSH**
  copy the files via ssh to another device/computer

Good luck!