# Virtualbox Ubuntu Image Username / password

Tags: virtualbox, password, username

First of all **I am totally new to Linux**. I decided to load Ubuntu Linux on Virtualbox and found an ova file here:

https://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/01/15/snappy-ubuntu-core-now-on-the-hypervisor-of-your-choice-with-ova/

It runs fine but when it boots up it is asking for a username / password. I've looked around and can't seem to find it. Can someone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Can we get a screenshot of this login prompt? Do you get a GUI, or just a terminal? If you could give us those, it would help a lot. As a side-note, try logging in using the username `ubuntu` and a blank password - worth a shot.

Comment: It's just a terminal. I just assumed that it would be root/root but nothing seems to work. I can't post an image because I have to have "10 rep points" before I can. Here is what the screen says:

Ubuntu Vivid Vervet (development branch) localhost.localdomain tty1
localhost login: [root]
password: [root]
Login incorrect
localhost.localdomain login: 

That's about it. Perhaps I should just download & install instead of using this .ova. It just seemed convenient.

Comment: Did you try logging in as user `ubuntu` with a blank password like I suggested? Logging in as `root` with password `root` wouldn't work, because by default root doesn't have a password and as such, can't be logged in as.

Comment: Yes, I did try the ubuntu / [blank] as you suggested but with no luck. Sorry I forgot to mention it.

Comment: Okay. Did you try the suggestion in the answer below? user/password = **"ubuntu"** / **"ubuntu"** (remove the quotes of course)

Comment: If you're new to Linux I doubt you want Ubuntu Core (it's a headless distro, meant for servers and IoT embedded devices). You should use regular-old Ubuntu Desktop: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: Try this site https://virtualboxes.org/images/ubuntu/ It has all the images plus their passwords.

Answer (score 2):

Boot into a root shell: [How do I boot into a root shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell)

Then change the password for your user (ubuntu)

```
sudo passwd <username>
```

Or create a new user

```
sudo adduser <username>
```

Answer (score 1):

The default user and password for a Ubuntu Core image like the one you download is "**ubuntu**" and "**ubuntu**" (without quotes).

But this is just a bare image (just the base system nothing installed) of a new alpha installation system designed for cloud computing. It's called [snapy](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/tools/snappy#snappy-local) and it's not likely what you are looking for.

Comment: I downloaded an ubuntu VMware image from https://sourceforge.net/projects/ubuntu-desktop-20-04-vmware/. I tried entering ubuntu as the username & password both. But the password doesn't work. Any idea?