# username/password for ubuntu cloud image in virtualbox

Tags: 22.04, ubuntu-core

I have downloaded ubuntu cloud 22.04 ova image from below link and started the same in virtualbox 7

https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/jammy/current/

On boot up it asks for username/password as shown below

[image]

I have tried ubuntu/ubuntu as UN/PW as mentioned in below link and it is not working

[Virtualbox Ubuntu Image Username / password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574501/virtualbox-ubuntu-image-username-password)

As shown below it says login incorrect

[image]

Any suggestions how to solve this issue would be of great help

Comment: Added the requested information @user535733

Comment: Also updated the Headline with the Ubuntu Cloud image .. looks like instead of using ubuntu core image I ended up with ubuntu cloud image.