# Nvidia 8400 glitches on Ubuntu 14.04 with HDMI

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, hdmi

I have an Nvidia GeForce 8400 card. Everything looks fine when the PC is booting, and I can also see the Ubuntu loading screen, but when it's time to show the login screen I see some strange freezes like multiple colors on my screen and then it becomes black and there is no way to get back.

I also tried to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> but I don't get a shell prompt. `nvidia-current` and `nvidia-settings` are already installed.

Answer (score 0):

login to a [root shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell)

then:

```
apt-get remove --purge nvidia

apt-get update

apt-get install nvidia-current

reboot
```

when logged in run in terminal:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig

gksudo nvidia-settings
```

Comment: it doesn't work, i started thinking my graphic card is broken but it is quite strange because simple screens like text and so on are shown. also dvi doesn't work at all

Comment: can you login to root shell?if your graphic card was broken you wouldn't do pretty much to anything even loading.

Comment: Not with the graphic card i want to use, to do it i have to switch to another graphic card.

Comment: Actually if looking at the images during the boot and also the bios menu, they are not rendered properly.

Comment: if you have two video cards try to run and disable them one by one in bios or remove if it's possible, to be sure which one causes the conflict and if you have two video cards you had to mention it.

Comment: I have 2 but i don't use them togheter

Comment: try to start system with one video card on board.

Comment: That's what i do every time, i'm not using two cards at the same time

Comment: I'm confused then... can you get to a root shell? if you got broken video card you have to test it then to fix it at customer service e.g..