# Problem booting after updating from Ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04

Tags: nvidia, 15.04

I just updated my laptop from Ubuntu 14.10 to Ubuntu 15.04.  Now on a restart it fails to make it to the login prompt.  The system looks to be in a cycle of failure and I see the message repeatedly

```
[ OK ] Started Light Display Manager.
[ OK ] Started ACPI event daemon.
       Starting ACPI event daemon...
       Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service....
[ OK ] Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
```

The contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` show a segfault.  Sorry I can't copy the backtrace now, but the chain goes

```
/usr/bin/X
/usr/bin/X
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
/usr/bin/X
/usr/bin/X
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/usr/bin/X
Segmentation fault at address 0x41
```

I'm on a Dell Precision m3800.  Since the nVidia driver is implicated in the stack trace, I'll start with swapping that out.

Any suggestions for my next steps to try to fix this?

thanks,
Dennis

Comment: We might have the same problem, look at this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1447978

Comment: Thanks @Mondane So I tried booting into recovery mode and installing a different nvidia driver, but now my problem is that I can't get networking to function in recovery mode.  It might be because the Dell Precision m3800 has a USB-to-ethernet adapter.  Or it might be I don't know the arcane commands to get networking to work.

I have spent several hours trying to get this to work and I'm close to just wiping the machine and installing fresh.  I hate to do that because I'm going to lose a day of productivity.

Comment: A similar question is http://askubuntu.com/questions/613577/ .

Answer (score 6):

I was able to fix this after reading the bug report @Mondane mentioned and several other troubleshooting articles on recovery mode.

1. Boot into GRUB menu (pressing shift while starting).
2. Choose recovery mode.
3. Enable networking.
4. Drop to root shell prompt.
5. `ifconfig eth0` and `dhclient eth0` to get
6. (Probably unnecessary)  I had a some networking issues that were probably unrelated to this (undetermined so far) so I had to edit `/etc/resolv.conf` to include Google DNS `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.
7. See what drivers are available for the nvidia hardware: `ubuntu-drivers devices`
8. Install the recommended: `apt-get install nvidia-346`
9. Reboot normally.
10. Go to sleep.

Some resources I found useful:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode#Booting_into_recovery_mode
- [How do I boot into a root shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell)
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

For reasons I haven't yet determined, my networking was really messed up.  I had to unplug and replub the USB-to-ethernet, run `dhclient`, then `apt-get install nvidia-346` to get about 5% of the update before networking failed.  This might be a hardware issue and totally unrelated, but it made troubleshooting and fixing this problem especially difficult.

Comment: This worked for me too. Dell XPS15

Answer (score 0):

The Dell-provided USB 3.0 to Gigabit Ethernet adapter uses a Realtek chipset. When I updated to kernel 3.19, I had to fetch the latest r8152 driver from  [their site](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=56&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false).

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following works on mint 19:

choose recovery mode in grub, then resume to normal boot (this way you can skip the endless running job). Then in the normal desktop, switch nvidia driver.