# Can't boot after upgrading from 14.10 to 15.04

Tags: upgrade, 15.04

I just upgraded an installation of 14.10 x64 that was installed from scratch not long ago. I upgraded from the update manager because it suggested to do so.

It finished successfully and I rebooted.

After reboot I get stuck with a blank screen and I can't type anything.
Also, I hear the tamtam sound looping every 5 seconds.

I saw other similar questions with answers but it does not work for me.

I can't ctrl-alt f1. It is not doing anything.

I burned a Ubuntu DVD x64 15.04 and can boot with it but I have no idea what to do next.

Please, if you want to help, I am not familiar with terminal commands.

Thank you.

Comment: One similar question is http://askubuntu.com/questions/613577/

Comment: What is "LiveCD recovery crosslinks"?

Comment: I have looked at the links but I can't see how it can help me.