# bumblebee on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 15.04 on it and Nvidia video card GT840M. I've installed video driver in a way like this:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

After that I've installed bumblebee and primus

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee
sudo apt-get install bbswitch-dkms
sudo apt-get install primus
sudo systemctl enable bumblebeed
```

In `/etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf` I've added lines

```
i915
bbswitch
```

And in `/etc/modprobe.d/nouveau.conf` I've added line

```
blacklist nouveau
```

Almost everything works fine. In nvidia-settings (`sudo gksu nvidia-settings`) I selected CPU I want to use `Intel (power saving mode)` and my discret video card is off by default (as I wanted, because I need my laptop at the university where I don't have a lot of sockets to charge it and turned on video card uses a lot of energy). When I start my PC and type `lspci -v` I have a message

```
03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
!!! Unknown header type 7f
```

Which says that my card is turned off -- everything is fine now.

`The problem is` when I try to use my card, e.g. `primusrun firefox` it turns on and when I stop firefox it doesn't turn off back. So I keeps turned on and uses a lot of power. The only way to turn it off back is

```
# echo OFF > /proc/acpi/bbswitch
```

But I don't want to do it all the time I use it. How can do it automatically?

This problem has occured only when I started to use Ubuntu 15.04. Before it (I had Ubuntu 14.10) it worked fine.

Comment: I'm similar to Little Big MAC's answer. There's a Ubuntu Launchpad bug that I put a similar description and instructions up on. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bumblebee/+bug/1457150

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that editing the /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf to match your installed driver. Your file should look like this for your current configuration. When this is configured it will automatically enable and work when using the `primusrun` command and after exiting the program it will shut it off.

```
# Configuration file for Bumblebee. Values should **not** be put between quotes

## Server options. Any change made in this section will need a server restart
# to take effect.
[bumblebeed]
# The secondary Xorg server DISPLAY number
VirtualDisplay=:8
# Should the unused Xorg server be kept running? Set this to true if waiting
# for X to be ready is too long and don't need power management at all.
KeepUnusedXServer=false
# The name of the Bumbleblee server group name (GID name)
ServerGroup=bumblebee
# Card power state at exit. Set to false if the card shoud be ON when Bumblebee
# server exits.
TurnCardOffAtExit=false
# The default behavior of '-f' option on optirun. If set to "true", '-f' will
# be ignored.
NoEcoModeOverride=false
# The Driver used by Bumblebee server. If this value is not set (or empty),
# auto-detection is performed. The available drivers are nvidia and nouveau
# (See also the driver-specific sections below)
Driver=nvidia
# Directory with a dummy config file to pass as a -configdir to secondary X
XorgConfDir=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d

## Client options. Will take effect on the next optirun executed.
[optirun]
# Acceleration/ rendering bridge, possible values are auto, virtualgl and
# primus.
Bridge=auto
# The method used for VirtualGL to transport frames between X servers.
# Possible values are proxy, jpeg, rgb, xv and yuv.
VGLTransport=proxy
# List of paths which are searched for the primus libGL.so.1 when using
# the primus bridge
PrimusLibraryPath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
# Should the program run under optirun even if Bumblebee server or nvidia card
# is not available?
AllowFallbackToIGC=false


# Driver-specific settings are grouped under [driver-NAME]. The sections are
# parsed if the Driver setting in [bumblebeed] is set to NAME (or if auto-
# detection resolves to NAME).
# PMMethod: method to use for saving power by disabling the nvidia card, valid
# values are: auto - automatically detect which PM method to use
#         bbswitch - new in BB 3, recommended if available
#       switcheroo - vga_switcheroo method, use at your own risk
#             none - disable PM completely
# https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Comparison-of-PM-methods

## Section with nvidia driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nvidia
[driver-nvidia]
# Module name to load, defaults to Driver if empty or unset
KernelDriver=nvidia-340
PMMethod=auto
# colon-separated path to the nvidia libraries
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-340:/usr/lib32/nvidia-340
# comma-separated path of the directory containing nvidia_drv.so and the
# default Xorg modules path
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-340/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

## Section with nouveau driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nouveau
[driver-nouveau]
KernelDriver=nouveau
PMMethod=auto
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau
```

Comment: Sorry that I have not been checking your answer for so long, but thaks a lot! That really worked!

Comment: No problem. I am having a somewhat similar problem with my 14.04 setup. I can run and activate the card but it won't turn off unless I run "sudo rmmod nvidia" then run "tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<< OFF".

Comment: My post on my current issue is <http://askubuntu.com/questions/654868/bumblebee-not-switching-card-off>

Comment: thanks @Dima and Little, these posts solved my problem. I was not even able to run primusrun or even start bumblebeed, but then purging everything, even reinstalling xorg-video-intel and so on and reinstalling following your steps, I managed to get optirun and primusrun working. Very importantly (not obvious to me) reboot after every change of conf.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it "automatically", per se, but you could just try putting a shellscript on your desktop and then running it every time you close whatever program you're using. Not necessarily what you're looking for, but a temporary, less tedious solution, at least.