# Ubuntu 15.04 amd64 Asus N550JK Laptop Hibernation Problem

Tags: nvidia, suspend, hibernate

My computer (N550JK) has 12 GB of RAM and 1.5 TB HDD storage. My HDD contains 16 GB swap partition, which should be enough to hibernate, I think.

I have made a fresh install of Ubuntu. Since my graphics card (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 850M) is very messy with `nouveau`; I have started the live CD with `nomodeset` kernel argument, it I don't do this I get a lot of errors and my system hangs. After I have successfully installed my Ubuntu with latest updates and 3rd party software such as flash, decoders, etc. When I started Ubuntu, as a result of nouveau-incompatibility; I had a login loop etc. I followed these links and solved my graphics card issues (actually I hope):

- [15.04 and Nvidia: login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614128/15-04-and-nvidia-login-loop)
- http://rajat-osgyan.blogspot.com.au/2015/03/how-to-install-bumblebee-on-ubuntu.html

I have installed `nvidia-352` drivers from PPA, and `bumblebee` from Ubuntu repositories.

Since my keyboard has non-functional screen brightness FN keys, I have added `acpi_osi=` kernel arguments to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` part of the `/etc/default/grub` file. And it worked! My FN keys issue is solved!!!
For informative purposes, I also removed `quiet splash` kernel options.

I have mentioned all of those above because they are the only things that I have done after installing linux.

Well, here is the main point. At first after being sure that my graphics card configuration is fine, I have run the `pm-hibernate` as root, and then it worked! :D Then, I decided to enable it on power menu, so followed instructions at this link:

[How to enable hibernation in 15.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614662/how-to-enable-hibernation-in-15-04)

Then, I used my power menu to hibernate, it seems it hibernates well. But when I try to resume, I got,

- Messages related to loading image from swap.
- `Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)` (this is the last message)

Then, my system hanged.

After that I was curious, did I get the same problem with `pm-hibernate`? So I used `pm-hibernate` to hibernate again, and the problem occured again.

So what should I do to make hibernation work? If you need further information I can take snapshots of my system, record a video or send log files you want.