# System is unable to boot after upgrade to 15.04. Version 219

Tags: upgrade, loop-device

I wanted to upgrade my system from  Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04. When the upgrading process finished after reboot I get infinite loop "version 219" on the black screen. I have been browsing a lot but didn't find nothing that would help me. I use AMD.

Comment: refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/614128/15-04-and-nvidia-login-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Restart your system, or shut it down and then power it on again.

Press and hold down the `shift` key immediately and keep it held down while the system starts to boot, in order to force the `Grub Menu` to appear.

Once the "Grub Menu" appears, release `shift` and then press the `e` key to enter edit mode.

Use the `down arrow` key to move the cursor to the line beginning with the word `linux`, then press the `end` key to move the cursor to the end of that line. Normally this will be just after the words `quiet splash`.

Press `space` to add a blank space after `splash` then carefully type in the kernel boot parameter: `noapic acpi=off`

Press `Ctrl + X` to boot the system using the parameters you've added.

To permanently add a kernel boot parameter, log in to the system and start a terminal window --- `Applications` --- `Accessories` --- `Terminal`

In the terminal window at the `$` prompt, enter the command:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Enter your password when prompted by `sudo`.

In the editor window, use the arrow keys to move the cursor to the line beginning with:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
```

Then edit that line, adding the parameters `noapic acpi=off` to the text inside the double-quotes after the words quiet splash, be sure to add a `space` after splash before adding the new parameters

Click the `save` button, then `close` the editor window.

In the terminal window at the `$` prompt, enter the command:

```
sudo update-grub
```