# install nvidia drivers with ppa into Ubuntu 15

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I use a Ubuntu 15(desktop) + KDE Plasma 5 into a Vagrant Box.
I have problem with my resolution screen.

For resolve this I want to install NVIDIA drivers on my Ubuntu. It seem to be more goodly than install this with the ppa way.

I'm helping with this official howto : [Ubuntu NVIDIA install](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/nvidia)

- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` => OK
- `sudo apt-get update` => OK
- `ubuntu-drivers devices` this return me this :

[image: result ubuntu-drivers devices]

If I try to install the official .run file NVIDIA I have another problem.

**What is the process to install my NVIDIA GeForce 580GTX drivers on Ubuntu 15 ?**

**I need install VBoxGuestAdditions mandatory for using graphical drivers ?**

I try with Ubuntu 15 and Unity :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To install the latest driver on Kubuntu, first remove that PPA from `/etc/apt/sources.list` in a terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

Now add this one

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Now install the latest driver

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358
```

and reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Any extra information you need for your tutorial, please ask and I will add it to the answer :)

Comment: In virtualBox nvidia-361 package freeze my VM. In a packer build VM I have this return error : virtualbox-iso: E: Impossible to find the package nvidia-361. I'm finding what it's happening  and I tell you.

Comment: OK Sorry, try with the older driver, see my edit.

Comment: Nothing change with install drivers. Also install nvidia-settings package but nothing change.

Comment: Try install nvidia drivers directly on my vagrant launched with Ubuntu 15.04 (server + ubuntu-desktop). Install package nvidia ok but when I reboot and try to connect on screen login it redisplay again and again the screen login. I can't enter on my session.

Comment: See this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/614128/15-04-and-nvidia-login-loop