# Ubuntu Nvidia drivers GTX965m

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

So I am just about to rip the last hair out off my head over this. Been trying to setup a dual boot of windows and linux for the last 3 days since getting my new Alienware 15 r2 laptop and I am having no luck. I've gone through every thread I could find relating to this installation at least once and some multiple times and can't get it recognised/installed. I am fairly new to linux but I'm trying to break into it to utilise some of it's tools and I need my graphics card to work. I have ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed, and I have done multiple re-install's with different distros, and first had trouble getting the killer wireless to work and eventually gave up on the and just using a TP-Link usb.

But I just can't figure out the nvidia drivers, with each the different solutions out there. I am just very lost at the moment. Can anyone please help? Also, I am in Tasmania and the main fibre-optics cable between us and the mainland is down for maintenance and we're on a very congested secondary line, so my internet is Suuuuuper slow (300mb on a good server took over 3 hours to download), so I would prefer not to re-install ubuntu at this stage, because the updates and upgrade will probably take days...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Tried this http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers?

Comment: I have This is the screen I get http://imgur.com/AjrViwo

Comment: And when I choose either of the nvidia options, and apply, the selection just reverts back to the Nouveau option

Comment: What do you get from `sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-settings`?

Comment: I have also downloaded the actual .run file from nvidia and tried to install it through the console and get varying results with different methods from different threads. The closest I got was the screen showing the the nvidia drivers were starting to build and then an error occurs relating to the Nouveau drivers still running. And no matter what I do to stop the nouveau drivers, blacklisting etc. it still gives the same error. I've also tried it through PPA's and updates etc. etc. It's sorta bluring into one after spending so much time on this issue

Comment: http://imgur.com/rChQyGl this. Thanks for quick response!

Comment: Looks like a problem of conflicting drivers. Can you remove whatever is installed from the .run file. [This PPA](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) is ok to use if you want a newer driver.

Comment: so I did 
`sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-361.28.run --uninstall`
 Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yep, something like that. Did it work?

Comment: 'sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-361.28.run' - as you have already installed it...just execute this .run file and follow the on screen instructions to uninstall it.

Comment: I am referring to this answer from my other answers. I had a login loop issue as mentioned [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/721633/nvidia-graphics-card-driver-installed-led-to-login-loop).

Comment: Also what is the result of this command lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'

Comment: This is the result of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` http://imgur.com/yrV3nrB

Comment: This is the what I get when I run `'sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-361.28.run'` 
http://imgur.com/wnN05o7 & http://imgur.com/opoOcay

Comment: And when I run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-settings` again I get this? http://imgur.com/rChQyGl

Comment: Also, I get this line a lot for different things: `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`. Does it help?

Comment: So I am getting a whole lot of errors and failures all over the place, programs not running etc. I might just admit defeat for now and do a fresh install and leave it to download everything it needs overnight, and try the answer provided below by @Ashu and report back. Thanks for the help so far everyone! Really appreciated since I am highly dissapointed by my own progress so far :S

Comment: Please refer to this thread(http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) regarding some unmet dependencies issues.

Comment: So I tried your solution and I am now stuck with a looping login. I can probably fix that myself but how do I get these drivers to work other than that way?? :(

Comment: Well login loop can be due to this issue or several other issues. But you can still login using Ctrl+Alt+F1(F1 to F6) and then go to /var/log directory  to find out what might be causing the issue.

Comment: I fixed the login by removing the drivers. Tried to install again without "nomodeset" in the grub because I read here (http://askubuntu.com/questions/614128/15-04-and-nvidia-login-loop) that might help, but that just gave me a black screen upon reaching the login stage (the ubuntu sound plays, but no screen). Now I removed the drivers again, and I can login again. What should I do from here?

Comment: And what do you mean by "Maybe it is explicitly necessary to select the NVIDIA adapter in BIOS"?

Comment: In some of the systems - BIOS is being set to the default integrated graphics card as it consumes less battery and good for most of the applications. One need to explicitly set that to dedicated graphics card...in other words in some of the systems...this is controlled at the BIOS level.

Comment: No luck. I have now tried every thread I could find and I have tried this for Nvidia-361, 352 & 355. All yield same results. Infinit login... I have literally now spent 4 straight days over my long weekend trying to get this sorted and nothing.

Comment: anything else? otherwise I am gonna give up and check back in a few months to see if anyone else got anywhere because I see a lot of people with the same problem