# No Login after Update

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, 14.10, 15.04

I've got a pretty serious problem with an Ubuntu on my PC. I can't login anymore over the GUI. If I Login, the Login Screen just change to Black, and a few seconds afterwards the Login Screen appears again. In TTY it works...

I did a clean install from DVD about 7-8 times now, with different Versions. I tried Kubuntu, Xubuntu and even the normal Ubuntu. And the problem happens only if I allow Updates while installing, or do an Update afterwards.
But never updating Linux is not what I want.

I'm pretty desperate right now. I tried even to login over TTY and then do startx. But it just brings the Login Screen again....

I use a Lenovo Thinkpad W530. Don't know if it matters, or not.
It happened first with Kubuntu 14.10. After an Update a few Weeks ago. Please help.

Comment: try these:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/614663/kubuntu-15-04-upgrade-many-problems
http://askubuntu.com/questions/613577/vivid-vervet-upgrade-mess-flickeringo

Both are pretty recent...

Comment: Thanks for the links. But I saw both of them. But they do not work. Since I use the internal Intel HD Graphics Card. And it only happens after updating.   I tried to wait for a correct update, but after 2 months and 7-8 reinstall nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed the same issue a few minutes ago, my problem was that I had some issues with AMD drivers.

I fixed it with this: [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Specifically `chown username:username .Xauthority`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I did:

```
chown `id -u`:`id -g` ~/.Xauthority
```

Exist one command to create the file
[mkxauth](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkxauth)