# How to upgrade to the latest kernel

Tags: upgrade, kernel

I'm looking at the official repo, https://github.com/torvalds/linux - how would I replace the ubuntu 15.04 kernel (3.x) with the latest, 4.x one? My current system has the `x86_64` architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the kernals:

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0-vivid/linux-image-4.0.0-040000-generic_4.0.0-040000.201504121935_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0-vivid/linux-headers-4.0.0-040000-generic_4.0.0-040000.201504121935_amd64.deb
```

Install using:

`sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.0.0*.deb linux-image-4.0.0*.deb`

Note: Canonical does not recommend updating your kernal via this method, yet. Some hardware components may not work properly.

Comment: `wget  http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0-vivid/linux-headers-4.0.0-040000_4.0.0-040000.201504121935_all.deb` is needed to fix the missing dependency error

Answer (score 1):

Go here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/
Scroll to the bottom
Download 3 (maybe 4) debs to a folder somewhere:

```
linux-headers-VERSION-NUMBER_all.deb
linux-headers-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb
linux-image-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb
linux-image-extra-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb   # if available
```

Install the debs with whatever package manager front-end you use (is gdebi still around?), or use these commands:

```
cd /path/to/folder/where/you/put/the/debs

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Comment: Worth mentioning: you probably don't want kernels postfixed with `-rcδ`, they're, like, pre-release kernels for testing.