# How to reset ubuntu to default display settings after failed nVidia driver install attempt?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

This is the same dreaded story in Ubuntu with nVidia drivers ... I got a new machine with the K2200 nVidia card in it and now I'm unable to boot again after installing the latest nVidia drivers for this card. This machine is behind a heavy secured proxy and I need to do a lot of trial error before getting internet and the latest update version of trusty 14.04, but for this I also needed a desktop up and running therefore I installed the nVidia driver from its download site.

I would like to reset back the display settings to default or minimal display to have a working environment. How can I do that? Note I have done several attempts and the backup settings may be gone.

UPDATE (1)

To install the nVidia driver I did the following:

- Download the driver of Quadro K2200 from a different machine
- copy it into a USB drive
- Install the driver in the new machine.

UPDATE (2)

I managed to run

```
$ sudo ./NVIDIAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --uninstall
```

it acknowledged that nVidia was successfully uninstalled but still I still see no desktop after boot just the black screen of voidness.

Comment: So you only ran that NVIDIA-xxxxxxx.run script? Did nothing else? So run it again with "--uninstall".

Comment: Then give output of `for f in /etc/modprobe.d/*; do echo $f; cat $f | grep nouveau; done`

Comment: That was one command. If output is not empty, then you will need to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

1. From the black screen where the computer has stopped when booting it, open a text-only virtual console by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.
2. At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Now you are logged in to a text-only console, and you can run terminal commands from the console. In this example, assume that you have downloaded an NVIDIA driver file called `/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.72.run` from the official NVIDIA website to your Downloads folder and installed it.

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads ## change directory to the location of the graphics driver that you downloaded from the official NVIDIA website
   sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.72.run --uninstall   
   sudo reboot
   ```

   Replace the location and driver name in the above commands with the location and name of the driver that you installed. If you can't remember the name of the graphics driver file that you installed, use the `ls` command to list the contents of the directory where the graphics driver file that you downloaded is located.

When you reboot the computer it will be using the Nouveau default open source graphics driver that is built-in in Ubuntu.

Comment: This can also be done from a [root shell](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell) in case we really can't boot at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get into system console by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1, then login there and run

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

If you can't, then boot to recovery mode using grub menu, choose "root" option and run there:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
apt-get purge nvidia*
reboot
```

This is applicable to cases, when you installed Nvidia drivers normal way, using apt-get.

If you installed them according to some bad manuals with blacklisting nouveau and running a file downloaded from Nvidia site, it is another case.

The easiest way to uninstall Nvidia drivers is to run same file like that

```
./nvidia-xxxxxxxx.run --uninstall
```

And if you blacklisted nouveau, then you need to revert that too.

Comment: Even if nvidia was not installed via apt-get?

Comment: How was it installed? Please [edit] your question and write all steps you did to install. And what is the state now?