# ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS installation problem

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, display

I installed ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS on external hard disk. My main hardware is:
computer Acer Aspire 4530 pre installed with windows vista home basic.
Graphic card by nvidia GEForce 9100M G.
After installation and also installation of updates mandated by update manager
booting up was not possible from log in screen. While checking recovery options,I was informed that the graphic card and display drivers were not properly detected and hence the system cannot start. I was advised to manually
reconfigure the display drivers. How do I go about it?
I may mention that the earlier version 14.04.1 LTS was working ok and I was able to instal proprietary display driver for nvidia 9100 M G card.

Comment: I suspect I have a multitude of solutions in mind, but pertaining to configurations I cannot be sure I'm deciphering correctly from your post.  I should probably mention I happen to have that very model of acer aspire right here.  It is rather old and has some quirks of its own, but I consider it a very nice laptop overall.  I'm confused what you mean when you say you installed 14.04.2 after 14.04.1.  Do you mean you did an OS upgrade, or that you did a total re-install?  It makes a difference.  With fresh installs it is often important to have internet connected by wire.

Comment: The 14.04.1 LTS was installed on another computer w/windows home premium which developed problems and was unused for long.Ultimately, I removed the hard disk and made it an external hdd. On this, I made a fresh new installation of 14.04.2 via usb. The internet was available during installation for updates.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

> log into [recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell) from boot (hold shift at boot)
>
> select 'Advanced Options'
>
> Then select 'Recovery' option

Make sure you are connected to a network via cable, then select:

> Enable networking

Once the process completes select

> root

then type:

```
login
```

enter your username and password

then try:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source && sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic

sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*

sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates nvidia-settings-updates

sudo shutdown -r now
```

Additional info: [here](http://choorucode.com/2013/02/07/how-to-fix-nvidia-driver-failure-on-ubuntu/) and [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/how-to-fix-non-bootable-ubuntu-system.html)

Ubuntu Forums: [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2081649)

Comment: It worked perfectly.Only,while waiting for answer to the problem,I had downgraded to 14.04.1 via live usb.I had installed proprietary nvidia driver provided by ubuntu.It was still having problems which were resolved by the solution above.I will try to upgrade again to 14.04.2 via updates.I do not know what will happen to the nvidia driver but I guess I can use this method again,if required.