# Missing dependencies - Can't insall Mutate launcher

Tags: 14.04, launcher, dependencies

I'm trying to install [the mutate launcher](https://github.com/qdore/Mutate#from-repository) on Ubuntu 14.04, but I'm having problems with all the methods suggested in the readme.

If I use the ppa method I receive:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an 
   impossible situation or if you ependencies problem]are using the unstable distribution that some   
   required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-control-center :
     Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I tried installing those separately, but didn't work

```
sudo apt-get install libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libcheese-gtk23 is already the newest version.
libcheese7 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

What could I do?

Comment: Do `sudo apt-get install -f` install necessary dependencies?

Comment: Nope, it didn't!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package: `libcheese7`:

```
Description-en: tool to take pictures and videos from your webcam - base library
 A webcam application that supports image and video capture. Makes
 it easy to take photos and videos of you, your friends, pets or whatever
 you want. Allows you to apply fancy visual effects, fine-control image
 settings and has features such as Multi-Burst mode, Countdown timer
 for photos.
 .
 This package contains the base shared library.
```

The package `libcheese-gtk23`:

```
Description-en: tool to take pictures and videos from your webcam - base library
 A webcam application that supports image and video capture. Makes
 it easy to take photos and videos of you, your friends, pets or whatever
 you want. Allows you to apply fancy visual effects, fine-control image
 settings and has features such as Multi-Burst mode, Countdown timer
 for photos.
 .
 This package contains the base shared library.
```

Open the terminal and do the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then install whatever you're trying to install. To check if those packages were installed back automatically during installation process simply run:

```
sudo apt-get install libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I didn't really understand why though

Comment: if it works don't forget to mark it as solved! Put a tick under votes count on the left.

Comment: Is there a way to revert it? It probably messed up with something, since after reboot it doesn't load the desktop environment, it's just a black screen. Probably weird things are happening with the nvidia drivers

Comment: did you install those packages back? I mean `libcheese7` etc... If you're running 14.04.2 no need to revert it simply try reconfigure `X` `sudo service lightdm stop` if running, `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg-lts-utopic` and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and then `sudo service lightdm start`

Comment: I'd better recommend you `Synapse` instead of `Mutate` as to my opinion it looks kinda better.

Comment: I will try, at the moment I can't access ttys neither. Do you know how I can access those when ctrl+alt+F1 to F7 does nothing?

Comment: You can't even get to tty console? Then do it from recovery mode/root shell http://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell

Comment: I tried running those commands from recovery but it says xserver-xorg-lts-utopic is corrupted or not completely installed. So I reconfigured xserver-xorg but it didn't work. It says "Job failed to start" when starting lightdm. Moreover, it says "stop: unknown instance:" when stopping it

Comment: I'm moving the question here http://askubuntu.com/questions/642041/black-screen-cant-reconfigure-xorg

Comment: please don't leave this question open if it solved your issue on installing the desired *package* and the things that occured to you might not happen to everyone, in any way they can follow your *linked* question to these comments... Otherwise this thread will be deleted/closed in the future.