# Ubuntu 15.04 via virtualbox log in fails (using correct password).

Tags: virtualbox, 15.04, logging

New to Linux and Ubuntu and prior to making the permanent switch Ive installed the latest version of VirtualBox onto my windows 7 laptop to explore the OS and come accustom to it.
Ive downloaded ubuntu 15.04 from Linux directly and via a torrent linked through their website, and Im experiencing the same issue either way.
I basically get an error message; "System prgramme problem detected" prior to the log in screen loading. The log in screen then appears as if normal but when I log in with the correct details I receive a black screen, then an error message at the top saying; "System programme prblem detected, do you want to report the problem now?".
All the forums have seemed to get me no-where, when running a check using the command screen it does tell me that there are xsession errors (using command ls -lah) is this a significant possibilty to the problem or is there a better way of diagnosing the problem? Im not computer programming literate but definately capable of getting my head around it and learning all of the required knowledge.

Hope someone can help!

Kind regards

Skin Back

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your Ubuntu installation experiences a crash early at boot, and before you were able to login. This most likely is related to a bug or an incompatibility somewhere. To further find out what causes your virtual machine to crash you may try read the log files from a TTY which I believe you are able to access (press <kbd>Host</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>).

Most bugs will get fixed over time. So the steps to take are:

- Upgrade your Virtual Box appliance to the latest version (5.0 at the time of writing this)
- Perform an upgrade of your Ubuntu installation to receive all security updates and bugfixes. From a TTY (or if that fails from a [root shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell?s=1%7C5.1156)) issue the following commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  sudo reboot
  ```

If these measures did not help you may try to install the virtual box guest additions, wich can also be done from a TTY or a root shell:

- [How do I install Guest Additions in a VirtualBox VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm/22745?s=1|0.0000#22745)

In all cases we need the virtualbox to reboot for changes to take effect.