# Login loop after enabling Intel Virtualization in BIOS

Tags: login, virtualization, intel, x230

After Enabling Intel Virtualization technology and VT-x in the Bios of my Lenovo x230 (I needed it for Virtual Box), Ubuntu (14.04) will start normally until the Login screen appears. When I type the password of my account or try to login as a guest, screen will get black for a second (as usually when starting), but in this case the Login screen will appear again.

First I tried to disable the Virtualization but the problem remains.
Afterwards I followed all the possible posts like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) but nothing has changed.

I reinstalled Compiz, Xorg, lightDM and Unity. nothing changed
When I try to reinstall ubuntu-desktop I get this message

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> > ubuntu-desktop : Depends: checkbox-gui but it is not going to be installed
> >
> > > > > > Recomends: unity-webapps-common but it is not going to be installed
> > > > > >             Recomends: xul-ext-unity but it is not going to be installed
> > > > > >             E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Some ideas?
I'm an average user, not advanced

here is my syslog

[syslog Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Wmlt.jpg)

> Oct 13 20:10:43 kiwi colord: Profile added: icc-c334853219a2a271b24927392eba9e84
>   Oct 13 20:10:48 kiwi colord: device removed: xrandr-default
>   Oct 13 20:10:48 kiwi colord: Profile removed: icc-60ab2eab48592e92bb8e7f9486ef94d8
>   Oct 13 20:10:48 kiwi colord: Profile removed: icc-c334853219a2a271b24927392eba9e84
>   Oct 13 20:10:48 kiwi rtkit-daemon[1733]: Successfully made thread 6413 of process 6413 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
>   Oct 13 20:10:48 kiwi rtkit-daemon[1733]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
>   Oct 13 20:10:48 kiwi pulseaudio[6413]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Stale PID file, overwriting.
>   Oct 13 20:10:48 kiwi gnome-session[6289]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file udisks.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
>   Oct 13 20:10:48 kiwi colord: Device added: xrandr-default
>   Oct 13 20:10:48 kiwi colord: Profile added: icc-d142e4d3f2c942a66540781a97088d65
>   Oct 13 20:10:48 kiwi colord: Profile added: icc-b639d273db61154975e85b2ea000dflf
>   Oct 13 20:10:48 kiwi kernel: [ 1590.177958] compiz[6485]: segfault at 20 ip 00007fb15464f729 sp 00007fffbd2465f0 error 4 in swrast_dri.so[7fb1542c8000+744000]
>   Oct 13 20:10:48 kiwi gnome-session[6289]: WARNING: Application 'compiz.desktop' killed by signal 11
>   Oct 13 20:10:48 kiwi gnome-session[6289]: WARNING: App 'compiz.desktop' respawning too quickly
>   Oct 13 20:10:48 kiwi gnome-session[6289]: CRITICAL: He failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
>   Oct 13 20:10:49 kiwi colord: device removed: xrandr-default
>   Oct 13 20:10:49 kiwi colord: Profile removed: icc-d142e4d3f2c942a66540781a97088d65
>   Oct 13 20:10:49 kiwi colord: Profile removed: icc-b639d273db61154975e85b2ea000dflf
>   Oct 13 20:10:49 kiwi colord: Device added: xrandr-default
>   Oct 13 20:10:49 kiwi colord: Profile added: icc-60ab2eab48592e92bb8e7f9486ef94d8
>   Oct 13 20:10:49 kiwi colord: Profile added: icc-c334853219a2a271b24927392eba9e84
>   Oct 13 20:17:01 kiwi CRON[6689]: (root) CMD ( cd 18 run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
>   Oct 13 20:22:20 kiwi dbus[560]: [system] Reloaded configuration
>   Oct 13 20:26:15 kiwi dbus[560]: [system] Activating service name.'org.freedesktop.systemdl' (using servicehelper)
>   Oct 13 20:26:15 kiwi dbus[560]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1'
>   Oct 13 20:26:18 kiwi colord: device removed: xrandr-default
>   Oct 13 20:26:18 kiwi colord: Profile removed: icc-60ab2eab48592e92bb8e7f9486ef94d8
>   Oct 13 20:26:18 kiwi colord: Profile removed: icc-c334853219a2a271b24927392eba9e84
>   Oct 13 20:26:19 kiwi rtkit-daemon[1733]: Successfully made thread 7243 of process 7243 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
>   Oct 13 20:26:19 kiwi rtkit-daemon[1733]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
>   Oct 13 20:26:19 kiwi pulseaudio[7243]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Stale PID file, overwriting.
>   Oct 13 20:26:19 kiwi gnome-session[7110]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file udisks.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
>   Oct 13 20:26:19 kiwi dbus[560]: [system] Activating service name.'org.freedesktop.localel' (using servicehelper)
>   Oct 13 20:26:19 kiwi colord: Device added: xrandr-default
>   Oct 13 20:26:19 kiwi dbus[560]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.localel'
>   Oct 13 20:26:19 kiwi colord: Profile added: icc-d142e4d3f2c942a66540781a97088d65
>   Oct 13 20:26:19 kiwi colord: Profile added: icc-b639d273db61154975e85b2ea000df1f
>   Oct 13 20:26:19 kiwi kernel: [ 2520.928570] compiz[7314]: segfault at 20 ip 00007f94f5489729 sp 00007ffc47352d20 error 4 in surast_dri.s6[7f9445102000WWWW]
>   Oct 13 20:26:19 kiwi gnome-session[7110]: WARNING: Application 'compiz.desktop' killed by signal 11
>   Oct 13 20:26:19 kiwi gnome-session[7110]: WARNING: App 'compiz.desktop' respawning too quickly
>   Oct 13 20:26:19 kiwi gnome-session[7110]: CRITICAL: He failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
>   Oct 13 20:26:19 kiwi colord: device removed: xrandr-default
>   Oct 13 20:26:19 kiwi colord: Profile removed: icc-d142e4d3f2c942a66540781a97088d65
>   Oct 13 20:26:19 kiwi colord: Profile removed: icc-b639d273db61154975e85b2ea000df1f
>   Oct 13 20:26:20 kiwi colord: Device added: xrandr-default
>   Oct 13 20:26:20 kiwi colord: Profile added: icc-60ab2eab48592e92bb8e7f9486ef94d8
>   Oct 13 20:26:20 kiwi colord: Profile added: icc-c334853219a2a271b24927392eba9e84

Thanks

Comment: look like something is not right with your LightDM. Boot into terminal and inspect `/var/log/syslog` for clue. Enabling VT-x should not interfere anything with the display manager.

Answer (score 0):

after trying really everything, I found [this post](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+question/197479), thath gave me the idea of restarting with an old Kernel (I remembered that one or two days before the system updated the kernel)

I also removed the Intel Linux Graphics installer

> sudo apt-get autoremove --purge intel-linux-graphics-installer

I was using the kernel 3.13.0.65-generic with a login loop after enabling Intel Virtualization but it was not working anymore afterwards, even disabling intel virtualization in the BIOS

Now I use the kernel 3.13.0.63-generic without login problems in both cases, with or without intel Virtalization.

I will use the old kernel until I can jump over the 3.13.0.65 to the next one.

For people without experience, you will need to follow the first two steps of [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell)

After solving the issues I tried to install the Intel Linux Graphics again but it was not possible. It shows an error

> wrong distribution

I assume the driver was part of the Problem.

Hope this helps somebody