# Citatel has ruined my Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: boot, updates, error-handling

After installing updates 2 days ago, I got the screen below on startup. I don't know what a Citadel account is as I never had one!

I tried keying in my password but nothing happened (I tried different keyboards as well but still nothing is inputted). I also tried re-installing my OS but after a number of errors, an the 5 - 6 attempt I managed to get the install screen that stated that there was no OS detected. Obviously, formatting my computer is the last thing I want to do.

How can I restore my OS back to the way it was before installation?
[image]

Comment: Can you login as guest? What happens if you press CTRL + ALT + F3 and login that way? Does it take the user/password?

Comment: No. As I said before, I can't get the PC to respond to any keyboard I connect to it

Comment: Does your mouse work? Can you login in the guest session? Are you connected to VPN or some other network? Check the network icon, and see if there's any hint there.

Comment: And you are sure you did not do this: http://www.citadel.org/doku.php/doku.php?id=installation:start  I would start with a live session and see if this was installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the recovery mode of Ubuntu and drop to a root shell.

Follow the steps at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode or look at the question [How do I boot into a root shell?](https://askubuntu.com/q/92556/367990) which is more detailed and with screenshots.

This root terminal you could use to access the system and back up all your important data.

You can also e.g. examine `/var/log/apt/history.log` which logs packages installed/updated/removed through `apt` and maybe revert recent installations.

To get a list of all installed packages, run `dpkg -l | less`, but it will be a very long list. Therefore we use the `less` viewer to get a scrollable list. You can narrow it down to only show lines containing a specific pattern like "citadel", use `dpkg -l | grep -i "citadel" | less` (-i for case-insensitive matching).

Remove strange packages with `apt-get purge PACKAGENAME`.

Please respond if you could follow any of these methods and what results you achieved. We can probably continue with further steps then.

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot with a USB - DVD in rescue mode.
2. Mount the file system.
3. Make a copy of your data. Backup it.
4. Create new user, reboot again and try to login with this new user.
5. If nothing work. Reinstall.

Answer (score -3):

Mark, I suspect that you have encountered a ransomware virus. Try booting from a DVD.  Have a look at your hard drive.  Are all the folders OK or do they have strange names? I suspect that they will be encrypted files containing all your data. Certainly, trying to reinstall the OS will fail as this action is blocked by the virus.

This vulnerability is very new on Linux. However, I understand that it is not a good one and that it is possible to enter an unencrypt key yourself and free up the machine.  Unfortunately I have lost the article.

My advice is contact Ubuntu and ask advice as they must have encountered this by now.  Alternately, search Google for Linux ransomware virus solution.

I really hope I am wrong but I suspect that I am right in interpreting your OS's symptoms.

Comment: I'm sorry, but lets reanalyze your answer.  "My advice is contact Ubuntu and ask advice as they must have encountered this by now."  This is Ask Ubuntu, a community support medium, they've already reached out.  "Alternately, search Google for Linux ransomware virus solution."  Nothing here necessarily indicates that this is ransomware.  They have said "No OS Detected" occasionally pops up, which makes me think hardware issues.  There's no evidence, as well, that this *is* a ransomware infection, so you are just making unsupported assumptions.

Comment: 1. There are many forums - one of which may have helped.

Comment: (2): Irrelevant, the symptoms here don't match that of known ransomware on ANY distribution - having had first hand experience with ransomware this doesn't sound like a ransomware infection (there would be prompts for payment and instructions in order to 'pay' to get back the files, and there aren't any.)  (Also keep in mind I work in the IT Security industry, and ransomware doesn't present with the symptoms stated here, typically)

Comment: 1. There are many forums - one of which may have helped.
2.  I have recently had ransomware on a Win 7 machine.  What you describe sounds similar   

http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/12/16-ways-to-beat-cryptolocker-and.html

http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/96437/are-there-ransomware-infections-of-ubuntu-linux-in-the-wild

http://arstechnica.co.uk/security/2015/11/new-encryption-ransomware-targets-linux-systems/

3.  Have you booted from DVD?
4.  "No OS Detected" could originate from a number of causes.
5.  "unsupported assumptions"  yes.  Trying to be helpful.
Goodbye.