# My ubuntu 14.04.3 on VMware Player VM gets stuck in a login loop

Tags: gnome, login, password, password-recovery, recovery-mode

I used to use Guake terminal. When I was using last time Guake stuck and stop working. Pressed `F12` several times in order to close the terminal. Then system logged off and login screen shown up. Entered password for my username couldn't log in. Tried to login with Guest mode still couldn't log in. Then I googled, found some solutions: [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop). Then I tried to log into shell using  `Ctrl+Alt+F1` entered username and password still couldn't log in. Tried to get into recovery mode using this link [How do I boot into a root shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell). 
But [image: Picture 3] didn't show up.

I have no idea what to do!
 
How can I solve the problem?

Comment: So if you cannot login on tty1, double check your keyboard locale.

Comment: Your screenshot shows the "Recovery Menu", but you want to use tty1 to log in. For VMWare, it needs a little trick: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006012