# I entered "sudo chmod 770 /" on terminal. Is it fixable?

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, root, chmod

I was trying to deny permissions to access the root folder to all non sudoers, and had the (NOT) brilliant idea to run `sudo chmod 770 /`. Now I get permission denied for all commands.

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 on Virtual Box and the installation is encrypted.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I've read I can use a live environment to undo this but I don't know how to do it via Virtual Box, with an encrypted installation (I have the key, though).

Answer (score 4):

Luckily you haven't used `-R` option so you can easily revert it by following command:

```
sudo chmod 755 /
```

755 is the default permissions for the / directory.

Comment: This won't work.. Sudo is inside root so executing it is not permitted since you can't get into the folder

Answer (score 1):

Was able to fix it by booting into a root shell following the procedure in the answer to this question: [How do I boot into a root shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell) 
And entering `chmod 755 /`.