# Ubuntu 14.04 totally locked after replacing graphic card (gf 750 ti)

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, ati

I had an old ATI graphic card and was using the proprietary drivers on Ubuntu 14.04.
I replaced the card with a Geforce 750 ti and Ubuntu doesn't start anymore.
I cannot open a login screen with CTRL+ALT+F1, the system is totally locked.

My idea is to replace the card with the old one, uninstall the proprietary drivers and, afterwards, reinsert the new card and reinstall the correct drivers.

Would this procedure work? Is there an alternative one that does not force me to replace the hardware?

Comment: what do you mean by 'totally locked'????   "Failed to start x-server"????

Comment: I can see the violet color of the grub screen for a second and afterwards black screen. Pressing ctrl+alt+f<n> does nothing. I can only restart the PC pressing the button.

Comment: Can you boot into a [Root Shell](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell?) to install the [Nvidia proprietary drivers from ppa](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)?

Comment: Can you get into grub by pressing shift key...?

Comment: Already tried but pressing left `shift` does not work

Comment: If you cannot get into grub then, I think replacing the old card is the only option

Comment: I have access to ubuntu's files from windows thanks to `ext2fsd`, I'll try to modify `/etc/default/grub` from there and see if grub comes up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you had the proprietary AMD drivers installed, first remove them.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.
On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> ... enter  user name and password ...

Now execute the following commands :

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx*  
sudo reboot
```

Install the latest stable NVIDIA drivers 352 from the Ubuntu repositories.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.
On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> ... enter  user name and password ...

Now execute the following commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo reboot
```

Comment: and another good one :) +1

Comment: Ok thanks, fixed, but I used only half of your answer.
The reason is that, with a German keyboard, **I could not find a way to write a "=" character in the grub editor!** NO WAY! 
All the rest worked
NOTE: I had to ad a "*" to `"sudo apt-get purge fglrx"`

Comment: @marco : You're welcome - I add the * to the command in the answer ... enjoy ubuntu experience ! :)