# How do I fresh install when Ubuntu doesn't come with my Graphics Card driver?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, system-installation, graphics

I've been using Ubuntu on my laptop for years, but I've just built a new desktop and can't install Ubuntu. Looking at my graphics card online, I can tell that Ubuntu doesn't come with drivers for it. I've determined that [this is the driver](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/5892503) I need, but I have no way to install it. Ctrl+Alt+F1/4/11 and others have no effect.

Is there any way around this? Can I load the driver on to the install USB from another computer? I currently have Windows installed on my new PC (I'd be installing Ubuntu on a different drive) and Ubuntu MATE 14.04 on my laptop.

My Graphics card is an EVGA Nvidia GeForce GTX 750ti.
Thank you.

Comment: Also, I've tried this with (14.04): Official Ubuntu, MATE, Lubuntu & Xubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that happened to me, ubuntu 14.04 in its first version had an old nvidia driver included that was not compatible with recent chipset nvidias (the 750ti was fairly recent back in those days) so it wont boot. however, if you make the iso with netbootin you will get a "run with compatibility video mode) and basicly it will load with a generic vesa driver with no video aceleration,it will load a very buggy desktop then all you need to do is control alt t , add the ppa for nvidia drivers

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
and you should have your video trouble sorted.

Or as an alternative try using this version of 14.04 - Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS from the ubuntu site as its a more updated version and maybe it has the updated drivers already.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I'll try it now and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you, there was actually no low graphics mode shown on my pc but there was on my laptop for some reason. Ended up putting the drive in my laptop and installing from usb that way, then switching drive back out. Ubuntu usb install should boot in low graphics mode by default and ask the user to pick from some selected recommended drivers, download one from the internet or stay on vesa. Thanks for the help though, I'd never seen the driver you mentioned and it worked like a charm.

Comment: That ppa is the nvidia oficial repository ; you can install all their drivers from there

Answer (score 0):

The way I installed drivers for the 750ti those days when Ubuntu 14.04 would not boot was as follows:

1. Do not insert the external card, or disable it in BIOS.
2. Install Ubuntu using the built-in internal VGA.
3. Enable the [graphics drivers ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)
4. Shut down
5. Install the external graphics card or enable it in BIOS
6. Boot into a [root shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell)
7. Install the appropriate driver (from ppa)
8. Reboot