# Failed to start Load Kernel Modules Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, networking, grub2, kernel

Yesterday I was booting up my computer and it gave me this error message:

[image]

I was searching for a solution and came across this forum discussion :
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2326216

So then I booted into recovery mode from the grub boot menu, as someone suggested and then try to run `$ sudo apt-get update`.

Here is where I started struggling. I cannot get my computer to connect to the internet.

`$ ping google.com` just gives me `ping: unknown host google.com`

So then I tried to run `$ sudo dhclient eth0` but it returned this error message:

```
run-parts: failed to stat component /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/debug: No such file or directory
run-parts: failed to stat component /etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/debug: No such file or directory
run-parts: failed to stat component /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/debug: No such file or directory
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
run-parts: failed to stat component /etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/debug: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT: `journalctl | grep modules` gives me:

```
 systemd-modules-load[214]: Inserted module 'lp'
 systemd-modules-load[214]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
 systemd-modules-load[214]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
 systemd-modules-load[214]: Failed to find module 'rtc'
 systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status1/FAILURE
 systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Unit entered failed state
 systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
```

Comment: Silly question - did you enable networking? (Also, did your computer boot after the error message? Can you reproduce it? If you can boot in normal mode and you get the same error, you can see which modules failed to load with `journalctl | grep modules` and you could [edit] your question to add this information )

Comment: No the computer didnt boot.. and yes I can reproduce it. How can I enable networking? I havnt found a way to do so.

Comment: Away from my computer... didn't you get [this dialog](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell)? Maybe it's out of date...

Comment: Well after I select the "Recovery mode" and boot into it, I don't get any other dialog. just gives me a tty and I can login.

Comment: Ok... can you do `sudo mount -o rw,remount /` and then  `sudo dhclient eth0` (assuming eth0 is the right interface)

Comment: No it will give me the same error

Comment: Hmmm! I have to check my system later but you should be able to fix the problem with rtc module without internet. I'll be back (if nobody else gives you a good answer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43597/discussion-between-zanna-and-fullk33).

Comment: @Mitch please undelete this answer. I guess it got deleted because my other question had the same, but that was a mistake on my part. The answer belongs to this question, that's why I removed it on the second one.

Answer (score 7):

OP solved their problem as follows:

`[FAILED] Failed to start Load Kernel Modules` was a red-herring. `rtc` is an obsolete module. The error message was removed by switching to tty1 (ctrl+alt+F1) and commenting out `rtc` (putting `#` at the start of the line) in `/etc/modules` (using sudoedit).

Now the computer would just boot to a blank screen.

Again in tty1, I then tried to connect to the internet, but `sudo dhclient eth0` gave me this error message :

```
failed to stat component /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/debug: No such file or directory
failed to stat component /etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/debug: No such file or directory
```

It turned out broken symlinks were to blame for that so to fix it:

```
cd /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d
sudo rm debug
sudo ln -s ../debug.dbkg-new debug`
```

and then

```
cd /etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d
sudo rm debug
sudo ln -s ../debug.dbkg-new debug
```

So then it was possible to do `sudo dhclient eth0`

`ping google.com` returned `unknown host google.com` but `ping 8.8.8.8` worked fine, so this was fixed by doing `echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf` as advised by steeldriver in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/809818/unable-to-ping-any-hosts-ifconfig-eth0-connection?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1223886_809818)

With internet connected at last, all problems were fixed by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt full-upgrade -f
sudo apt -f install
```

Comment: The same approach solved the same problem which occurred after an upgrade to 16.04 LTS from 14.04 LTS.