# Unable to ping any hosts, ifconfig: eth0 connection

Tags: networking, kernel

My problem started with this question: [Failed to start Load Kernel Modules Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/809199/failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules-ubuntu-16-04)

Now I can boot but only log in on tty1. I am trying to get `sudo apt-get update` to work to try and fix all the other issues. The problem is, that I can not connect to the internet. `ifconfig` tells me that I have a connection, and `sudo dhclient wlan0` and `sudo dhclient eth0` now execute successfully, but pinging any host won't work via hostname (I always get a `unknown host` error). I can successfully `ping 8.8.8.8` though.

`service network-manager status` shows `active` and `running`

`ip route` has a default route `default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0`

How can I connect to the internet?

Comment: If `ip route` (See `man route;man ip-route`) does not show a `default` route, you will have to add it via something like (YMMV): `ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0`

Comment: checked `ip route`. It shows a default route though. `default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0`

Comment: Have you tried to ping by IP, or only by hostname?

Comment: I tried `ping google.com`

Comment: Try `ping 8.8.8.8` - if that works, then it's most likely just a DNS issue

Comment: oh yes that worked!

Comment: OK in that case try `echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf` which will (temporarily - until you reboot, or restart the resolvconf service) hardwire your system to use one of the google public DNS servers. Then try `ping google.com` again. If that works, try your `sudo apt-get update` once more.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are booting in single-user, networkless, failsafe level.

To fix your DNS issues, just:

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then at least from that session, you should be able to ping by hosts. Assuming **8.8.8.8** is ping-able (as you stated) and that it is one of google's free DNS servers.

This way, while you'd have DNS servers set up, it is not guaranteed that apt-get will work. As a fail-safe boot, partitions might have been mounted read-only or not mounted at all.

If you can't create/edit **/etc/resolv.conf** because the filesystem is mounted read-only, as being root you can fix that (assuming the filesystem **can** be mounted read-write -- i.e. not a hardware limitation) with:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Then do the command again to set the nameserver. Assuming **/etc** is a directory under partition mounted in **/**, and no dedicated partition for **/etc**.

To add another DNS server (append) to the file:

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.4.4" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: by "pingable" I meant "reachable". i.e. if your ISP filters access to DNS services, you might want to use your ISP's provided DNS server address (or maybe your modem or router's IP address -- if cable, adsl, this may be the case!). They may block effective DNS access while still letting ICMP (ping) requests go!

Comment: Ok thank you, I will try doing this as soon as I can.