# Ubuntu 16.04 Failed to start Load Kernel Modules

Tags: boot, 16.04, kernel

Yesterday I was watching a video on youtube and suddenly my laptop got frozen.
I wasn't able to even move my cursor, so I gave it 10 min and after no response, I pressed the shutdown button for 5 seconds and rebooted my machine.

When it rebooted, it presented me the following screen:
[image]

Since than I've been searching the internet for any way to get pass this with absolute no luck.

Bellow I'll leave all the steps I've tried so far:
[First I was having problems enabling networking so these were the steps that helped me:]

- selecting the option `Advanced options for Ubuntu`

[image]

- choosing the option `Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-66-generic (recover
  mode)`
  [image]
- selecting the option `Enable networking` from the Recovery Menu

[image]

- when it finishes and returns to the Recovery Menu, I select the
  option `Drop to root shell prompt`
- and then running the following commands with my Ethernet cable
  plugged in did the trick:

Commands:

```
/etc/init.d/networking start
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then I followed this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/779574) referring to this [link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2318779&p=13466943#post13466943) and repeated the commands for about 10 times each in random order as described in the post:

```
apt-get update
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get -f install
```

And I also tried this: [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/823213)

```
cd /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d
sudo rm debug
sudo ln -s ../debug.dbkg-new debug
cd /etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d
sudo rm debug
sudo ln -s ../debug.dbkg-new debug
```

After all of that, my machine is still showing the screen in the first image.
At this point I don't know what more can I try so I really need some light on this.

Don't know if this is relevant but this is my `uname -a`:

```
Linux rm-pc 4.4.0-66-generic #87-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 15:29:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Also when I executed `journalctl -xb` and this are all the red lines in the code:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Turn off `secure boot` in your BIOS. You've got a problem in your /etc/fstab file. Paste a copy into your question and we can take a look. And DON'T manually edit /etc/resolv.conf (it says that right in the file!).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I had to go into the recovery mode for the 64 Kernel (65 was showing but it wouldn't let me do the `apt-get update` even after enabling networking) then enabling networking. Then I did an `apt-get update` and the `dpkg --configure -a`.

It stalled in the middle of that showing `Loading Braille support`... I had to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to get out of it and then do it again to finish. I think I did this 3 times before it finished unpacking and installing the 66 Kernel.

Once that was done I was able to boot it fine. Once in the GUI I was able to do another `apt-get update`, `dpkg --configure -a` and everything was fine. I also ran `apt-get autoremove` to get rid of all the old kernels. I'm back up again!