# Xubuntu failed to start load kernel modules

Tags: boot, kernel

I booted my pc today and everything was fine. An update was installed and I clicked on restart and then this error message appeared.

[image]

I found a similar problem here [Failed to start Load Kernel Modules Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/809199/failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules-ubuntu-16-04)

When I run `journalctl | grep modules` it shows this

[image]

I have internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a solution, so I used recovery mode to save my files and install XUbuntu again.