# Rolling back to non-HWE stack on Ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: 16.04, lts, hardware-enablement-stack

I recently updated the Ubuntu 16.04.1 version on my laptop to 16.04.2 and later updated the kernel and xorg to the HWE stack using this command

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

I have been experiencing heating, unexplained shutdowns, and other issues after this upgrade. Is there a safe way to roll back to 16.04.2 without HWE or should I format and reinstall? I tried this in the terminal but doing that caused ubuntu to freeze at the login screen.

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

Any suggestions please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You need to recover the original xserver-xorg.

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-core

sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop xserver-xorg libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

Answer (score 2):

Boot in [root shell](https://askubuntu.com/a/92558/21005).
Examine /var/log//var/log/apt/history.log (or older archives in the directory) to see which packages were removed together with xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04. Install them back.

Then run

```
sudo apt install --purge xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04- xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core \
xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-synaptics \
xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all \
xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-fbdev \
xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-qxl \
xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware
```