# Problem logging in at TTY

Tags: login, tty

I'm trying to fix the “the system is running in low graphics mode” problem. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to go to tty1 and login, it goes straight back to the login prompt. Why does this happen and how can I get to the terminal?

Running Ubuntu 14.04.5 on an Asus laptop with nvidia card.

EDIT: After i try to login it says `unable to cd to '/home/user'`

EDIT2:

```
$ namei -xl /home/* 
f: /home/user
$Drw-rw-rw- root root /
$drwxr-xr-x root root home
$drwxr-xr-x user user user
```

EDIT3: Thanks for the time and help. I booted Ubuntu from usb and backed up important files and reinstalled Ubuntu. It appeared that all files were changed to root? All directories like: `/home` `/opt` were binary and inaccessible files. Only as root I could navigate the directories and copy them to a usb.

Comment: Try ctrl + alt + f2

Comment: Same thing happens in all the tty 1-6. I've made vid and saw that it says "unable to cd to /home/user" for 0.1 seconds

Comment: You mean graphical login prompt?

Comment: This login https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdL7d7wBxk8. Just the black screen.

Comment: Please [boot into a root shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell) and run `namei -xl /home/*` and [edit] your question with the result