# Can't use my login password for su - postgres in terminal

Tags: command-line

I set my password to ir****3 when installing Ubuntu, but when I try to use `su - postgres` on terminal and enter tge same password it shows `authentication error: you are not a root user`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide an example of the command you get the error on, or is it you cannot login. By default Ubuntu installs without a 'root' login, so `sudo` asks for your password and not root.  Note: `sudo` is a command and not a login (it raises your privileges to root for the command that follows)

Comment: I want to develop the database in my ubuntu but whenever I type su - postgres in my terminal of ubuntu it asks for a password thar I dont have

Comment: I am entering my login password of ubuntu as a password in it but it shows as authentication error

Comment: It sounds like you haven't given 'root' a password yet.  Try setting a password  using sudo, ie. `sudo passwd`  (sudo will raise privileges to root then run passwd)

Comment: `su - postgres` would require a login password for user `postgres` - that's nothing to do with "login sudo on terminal" as stated in your question **nor** of the `root` account's login password.

Answer (score 7):

In order to run

```
su - postgres
```

you have to be `root` as the output says

=> If you are not `root` you have to run it with `sudo` like

```
sudo su - postgres
```

Or alternatively become `root` first using

```
sudo -i

su - postgres
```

---

Anyway both methods will only work, if your actual user is in the `sudo` group. You can check that listing all groups your user is in by running

```
groups
```

If it is not in the `sudo` group than you probably are not the one who installed this machine or have added this user afterwards.

By default the first added user during the installation is in the `sudo` group.

If this is the case you have to login as a user which is in the `sudo` group
(or if this is not possible you can boot into a `root` terminal following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/92558/423684))

and add your user manually to the `sudo` group running

```
sudo adduser <username> sudo
```