# I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, the X interface is not working

Tags: 16.04, xorg

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, the X interface (the same as ubuntu-desktop) is not working. I managed to get to terminal mode and do apt-get upgrade and apt get dist-upgrade to see if this should solve the problem. After that the same problem with the x interface persists. It does not allow me to do anything with the computer. Except that I can open Terminal by rightclicking the mouse. I have tried to solve the problem by reinstalling the desktop 'sudo apt --reinstall ubuntu-desktop' but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I boot into a root shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell)

Comment: Please note that Xubuntu isn't X on Ubuntu, it's an Xfce distribution of Ubuntu.

Comment: I found out that this is a bug in Ubuntu 16.04, I have upgraded to 18.04 which solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

To boot into single user mode you edit the boot instructions for the GRUB menu.

1. Hold down the left Shift key while rebooting to bring up GRUB menu.
2. Select (highlight) the GRUB boot menu entry you wish to use.
3. Press e to edit the GRUB boot commands for the selected boot menu
   entry.
4. Add the word "single" to the back of the line.
5. Reboot

Comment: of some reason holding down the left Shift key while booting does not work, I get to the ordinary login instead of the GRUB menu.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be without a solution so I upgraded to 18.04. Which solved the problem but created a new problem with WiFi access.