# ubuntu 14.04 OS not loading, /bin/sh problem

Tags: 14.04, bash, scripts

Lately I started learning SHELL SCRIPTING. I was practicing some commands. Unfortunately I did "mv test1.sh /bin/sh". In test1.sh which is my practicing script file which has "hello" text only. After that I saw the text moved to /bin/sh file. I shut it down. While restarting OS is not loading.
Note: I am able to see and select grub since I have dual OS(ubuntu,windows), but after selecting UBUNTU I am not able to see OS loaded. Please help me to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As `/bin/sh` in Ubuntu is just a symlink to `/bin/dash`, it is very simple to restore it:

[Boot to root shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell) and run these commands:

```
mount -o rw,remount /
rm -f /bin/sh
ln -s dash /bin/sh
```

Then restart and your system should work again.