# How can I boot into an Ubuntu command line without having to install Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

If I just download [Ubuntu Desktop](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and choose try Ubuntu without installing it will load into GNOME but the mouse is basically entirely unusable.

So what I would like to do is just try Ubuntu from the command line. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell if it hangs while loading the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch to the TTYs to get a command line. Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd> (or <kbd>F4</kbd> ...), and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> to go back to the GUI.

Comment: The live server installer lets you do the same. More details: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-live-server.html