# Failed to login even to terminal somehow enter is pressed

Tags: kernel, updates, keyboard

I fail to even log into recovery terminal, after I roll back to 4.4.0-142-generic kernel (because of error in nvidia driver in 4.4.0-143-generic kernel) after grub update. I login and then somehow additional enter is pressed and voilà, I have brick instead of PC.

Comment: Yes it is but know i cant even login in system!!!!!!

Comment: How to enter GRUB? I PRESSED left and right shift with no luck at all what is going?

Comment: Toggling left `<Shift>` many times just after BIOS splash would work.

Comment: esc worked for ne but anotber problem grub menu exists only half of a second and thrn enters grub consoke can i make load i need from there?

Comment: You need to select *Advanced options for Ubuntu* and choose previous kernel. See second screenshot https://askubuntu.com/a/92558/66509 . So you need to reboot machine, hold <Shift> key and enter *Advanced options for Ubuntu* menu in GRUB.

Comment: @N0rbert Shift does not work in my case but ESC does the problem is that Grub menu exists only 0,5 of a second and i can not choose anything BUT i have grub terminal and can do something from it, the quastion is csn i load from kernel i need?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91508/discussion-between-n0rbert-and-marat-zakirov).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by pressing  and   and praying to select other option to boot. I succeed and ffter it select 440-142-generic kernel and boot with it

I set
GRUB_DEFAULT='Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-140-generic'
in /etc/default/grub file
update-grub
reboot