# Can’t log in/boot Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: boot, command-line, nvidia, recovery-mode

I was updating my nvidia drivers from the ones that came with Ubuntu, then restarted and after it showed the Ubuntu logo it goes to a blank screen with a single blinking dash. I have read other questions like this but the answers did not work. I tried pressing escape to get to the terminal but it just printed a bunch of text and went back to the blinking dash. Control alt F2/3/etc (F10 does the same thing as escape) doesn’t do anything either, either do any of the shift keys. I don’t see how I can get to a terminal (recovery mode) or grub menu. Control alt T does not work either (does the same thing as escape). Basically I just need a way to get into a terminal.

Comment: This sounds like a "login loop".  Here's how to [How to boot into a root shell](https://askubuntu.com/a/92558/).  You should try to revert the changes that you made that preceded the problem's onset and then reboot.

Comment: Pressing escape or shift does not work like suggested in that answer. It might be of note that I installed ubuntu  on my old MacBook Pro 2010

Comment: This is gonna sound stupid.  Press alt+ctrl+f2 to open a console shell, then press alt+ctrl+f1 to return to the graphic console, and see if the login screen shows up.

Comment: You need to press whatever key brings you to the GRUB menu.  Consult device-specific documentation if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the GDM Nvidia rules works for me, with a similar problem; it may help you.

1. Boot into a Ubuntu Live ISO, and click <kbd>Try Ubuntu</kbd>
2. Open the "Disks" app
3. In the left panel, click on your system disk
4. In the main panel, select your root partition
5. Click the <kbd>▶</kbd> symbol towards the bottom left to mount the parition
6. You will see a "Mounted at" link appear next to the the "Contents" label

   [image]
7. Click on this link to open the location in Nautilus
8. From the Nautilus location bar, click the down arrow, and select "Open in Terminal"
9. In the terminal type the following

   ```
   sudo nano ./lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules
   ```

   (Make sure the path starts with `./` because you want to edit the `61-gdm.rules` file relative to the current *mounted* location).
10. Comment out all of the lines, as shown:

    ```
    # disable Wayland on Hi1710 chipsets
    # ATTR{vendor}=="0x19e5", ATTR{device}=="0x1711", RUN+="/usr/libexec/gdm-disable-wayland"
    # disable Wayland when using the proprietary nvidia driver
    # DRIVER=="nvidia", RUN+="/usr/libexec/gdm-disable-wayland"
    # disable Wayland if modesetting is disabled
    # IMPORT{cmdline}="nomodeset", RUN+="/usr/libexec/gdm-disable-wayland"
    ```

    [image]
11. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd>, and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save your changes and exit Nano
12. Remove you Live ISO and reboot

Comment: I figured I’d have to use a live usb/disk. It’ll be a pain but I’ll try it. I have to get a new flash drive and use another computer

Comment: There is a way to boot from an ISO stored on disk. (I do it regularly; that’s why there is a 5gb partition mounted in the Disks screenshot). Unfortunately, you need access to your system to set it up. Once you get your system working, you can search on this site how to boot into an ISO, in case you need it in the future.

Comment: I get a “directory ./lib/udev/rules.d does not exist”. Also I think I might be using Ubuntu 20.04 sorry

Comment: This will be the same for 20.04. Did you open the terminal by clicking the down arrow in the Nautilus location bar for the ~mounted~ file system? You can check that you are in the root of the mounted file system by typing `pwd` and it should give you a path like `/media/ubuntu/...`. Also, if you type `ls -l` you should see the typical Linux directories in `/` (`bin`, `boot`, `dev`, `etc`, `home`, `lib`, `mnt`, `opt`, `proc`, `root`, etc...). If you don't see those, is it possible you mounted the wrong partition on the wrong disk?

Comment: If I do just sudo nano /lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules instead of ./ it opens something but only had two of those lines. Otherwise nano opens up saying no such directory. I’m guessing doing that instead does not work as it did not solve the problem

Comment: Using `/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules` is incorrect, because you are attempting to edit the file on the ISO/USB. You definitely need to get to the root file system of the *mounted* location. Try navigating by typing `cd /media/ubuntu`. Then type `ls`; hopefully you will see a long directory name with numbers and letters. Then, `cd` into that and you will be at the right spot.

Comment: I just checked Ubuntu 20.10, and the `61-gdm.rules` file does have three attributes (`ATTR`, `DRIVER`, `IMPORT`) as shown in my answer above. So if you don't see all three, you are editing the wrong file.

Comment: I had to remake the live usb cause after what I did I couldn’t even open the terminal on the “try ubuntu”